# Is there a way to access the code inside of built in Java classes?

Tags: java, class

What I wondered, is if it was possible to open Java classes, like FileWriter, up to view the code inside of them.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The easiest thing to do is google "Java FileWriter source" and it will bring up pages that show the JDK source code. [Grep Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/FileWriter.java) is quite good too.

Comment: OK, that's useful. Thanks! I wanted to see what was inside of some classes so that if I wanted I could base code off them...and also for interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source code is usually downloaded for you with your download of the JDK. If not, you can go to the Java download site and find it. It should be in a src.zip file.

Comment: IDE's like NetBeans and Eclipse should do this automagically.

Answer (score 1):

The source code is all available at OpenJDK.  There is a (confusing) browser for the Mercurial repo.  Here is the code for [FileWriter in JDK7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/io/FilterWriter.java).

This is the [root of the JDK 7 code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/).